# Am I allowed to use L'Hospital rule after substituion or conversion to polar coordinate?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, limits-without-lhopital

I know that L'Hospital rule cannot be used for $2$ variable functions. But am I allowed to use it once I have converted it into polar coordinate or substitute it?

Here is an example:
$f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)\ln(x^2+y^2)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$

Here I can convert $x = r\cos(\phi)$ and $y = r\sin(\phi)$ then rewrite the function as $f(r) = \frac{\ln(r^2)}{\frac{1}{r^2}}$. Am I allowed to apply the L'Hospital rule here?

In another case, what if I substitute $x^2+y^2 = t$ then rewrite the function as $f(t) = \frac{\ln(t)}{\frac{1}{t}}$ then find the limit of $f(t)$ as $t$ approaches $0$ by applysing L'Hospital rule?

Comment: You're definitely allowed to use any method you want, including l'Hôpital's rule, to evaluate the new limits. The thing that needs justification is why the new limits give you the answer to the original limit. (I agree that they do; the justification has something to do with the limit of compositions of functions.)